# Which of these gives best performance/takes less resources?

Tags: android, performance

Consider having these two codes:

Code 1:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
```

Code 2:

```
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
```

Which one gives better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one is more resource-efficient! However if you reuse the `uri` variable you shall go with the first one, to keep the variable persistent. The difference is pretty much minor as the snippet of code will only need few resources to run so you will not have much of a gain. Consider that the garbage collector will get the uri object as soon as it is not referenced again. All in all, pick the second if you are tight with resources, though the difference is too small to consider, but the first one gives you a reusable object, which you shall consider if you need it again.

Comment: +1 for pointing out GC, -1 for not pointing that "intent" object may keep a reference for that Uri.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I forgot this! Constructive Criticism! :)

Answer (score 1):

People who say 2nd option is better/more resource efficient. Be careful you are creating same amount of objects in either case. It's just one extra **reference** to Uri object not an extra Uri **object**. Te size of a reference is **really** small, and really negligible. The only thing that matters about the 2nd one is that GC will collect Uri object as fast as it can, if there is no further reference to Uri object within **intent** object.